# set location of form instance

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]

I am working on this.. the locations of the marker is in the database..
this is **not** google's API.
this is [**GMap.Net**](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Demo.WindowsForms/Forms/MainForm.cs) for windows.

this is the code..

```
For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
        Dim marker As New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")))
        markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker)
    Next
```

I don't really understand so much, just experimented on code to get their supposed to be `latlng` and magically it appeared how I wanted it.

how can I make that look like this.. *(this is only an emulation, I just dragged the `form` to what place I want them to be)*
[image]
only `form2` and I only need its instances.. when I click the marker, `form2` appears right beside it.

**UPDATE:** I have my coordinates, but how can I make them appear like that? from my late versions, I use this.. `form2.Location = marker.LocalPosition + New Point(20, -240)` - to offset

but that code is pre-defined, hard coded. and that's not my goal. I want it on a sub, just like the code above (for markers)  thank you for helping.

**UPDATE2:** current code - shows the three forms, but does not go to the location of the markers

```
 For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
        Dim marker As New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")))
        markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker)
        Dim f As New Form2
        f.Location = marker.LocalPosition
        f.Show()
    Next
```

Comment: You can specify the FORM.Location if you have the coordinates

Comment: the form should have width and height properties.  I haven't worked with forms for a while, but the general code would be `form2.location = marker.localposition + New Point(20, -Form2.Height)`

Comment: I can't literally do that because that previous code is 'hardcoded' means everything I put in there is as it is. I want my program to be automated, and one the can dynamically add more. so I want it on a sub. that code is only effective if I have declared each of the `marker` which is not what I am looking for. Ask me if you need clarifications then I'll edit my question again. thanks for helping out